# Promise is returning timeout error [Timeout of 20000ms exceeded]

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, mocha

```
     Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartContract-lottery-fcc/test/unit/Raffle.test.js)
```

================================================================

**Error:**
Test `"picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money"` breaks at
`await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {}`

**Solution tested**:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607039/in-mocha-testing-while-calling-asynchronous-function-how-to-avoid-the-timeout-er#

**Result:** Did not work for me or implemented calling `done()`  and `resolve` wrong.

================================================================

**Code Block: Test**

```
              it("picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money", async function () {
                  const additionalEntrants = 3
                  const startingAccountIndex = 1 // deployer = 0
                  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
                  for (
                      let i = startingAccountIndex;
                      i < startingAccountIndex + additionalEntrants;
                      i++
                  ) {
                      const accountConnectedRaffle = raffle.connect(accounts[i])
                      await accountConnectedRaffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  }
                  const startingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLatestTimeStamp(
                      await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                          raffle.once("WinnerPicked", async function () {
                              console.log("Found the event")
                              try {
                                  console.log(recentWinner)
                                  console.log(accounts[2])
                                  console.log(accounts[0])
                                  console.log(accounts[1])
                                  console.log(accounts[3])
                                  const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
                                  const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
                                  const endingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLatestTimeStamp()
                                  const numPlayers = await raffle.getNumberOfPlayers()
                                  assert.equal(numPlayers.toString(), "0")
                                  assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")
                                  assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                              } catch (e) {
                                  reject(e)
                              }
                              resolve()
                          })

                          const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep("0x")
                          const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
                          await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(
                              txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId,
                              raffle.address
                          )
                      })
                  )
              })
```

================================================================

Has anyone encountered this problem? Or have a solution that would work, plz?

Thank you!

Comment: Mocha has a `timeout` property (in millisecond units) which you can override in a Mocha configuration file. See how I do it [here](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-packager/blob/61e42aa20add327e1a74ef7c5fbdd0a653509b11/.mocharc.yml).

Comment: Thank you for the info. It didn't work in my case. Time out was added to hardhat-config but the issue doesn't seem to be the length of the time out but something else. I maybe wrong.